# Can't change Dock size

Tags: macos, dock

I can't change the Dock's size. I tried deleting the file com.apple.dock.plist from the Preferences folder but it didn't resolve the problem.

[image: System Preferences Dock]

Answer (score 5):

After deleting the "/Users/YOURUSERNAME/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dock.plist" file you will need to reset the Dock for it to take effect. You can do this simply in a Terminal window with `killall Dock`.

You could also just try editing the plist file in a text editor. The `tilesize` parameter is the one that determines the dock size. It should look something like the following.

```
<key>tilesize</key>
<real>50</real>
```

You should also be able to resize the Dock by clicking on the dividing line between the application tiles and the file/folder tiles.

If resizing just doesn't work at all, there is a way to prevent changes to the Dock by making the size "immutable". If that has happened you can re-enable changes by entering the following commands in a Terminal window.

```
defaults write com.apple.dock size-immutable -bool false
killall Dock
```

Comment: If there are too many icons in the dock, it doesn't matter how much the slider size is increased, it won't make the dock any bigger.

Answer (score 0):

Download onyx an fix all the issues on the Mac with that app should work. Google it it's not on App Store although it should be it's awesome

Answer (score 0):

after deleting the plist mentioned above, hold the CTL+Alt(option) key and click Finder in the Dock, and choose "relaunch". That's all.